# DSolve running forever

Tags: differential-equations, error-tracking

[image]

I have no idea how to speed this up. Does maple do a better job at solving this?

Comment: The code in the question runs immediately if you add `Assumptions -> k/m > 0` to `DSolve`

Comment: @Coolwater nice observation. M was stuck integrating this, since it was under sqrt and by saying `k/m>0` bypasses possibility of complex numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know what you mean here. When I run (with $\omega=\sqrt{k/m}$):

```
DSolve[{y''[t] + \[Omega]^2 y[t] == 1/m Sin[\[Omega] t], 
y'[0] == 1, y[0] == 0}, y, t]
```

MMA (ver 11.2, macOS 10.13.1) provides this quite fast:

$\text{Function}\left[\{t\},\frac{4 m \omega  \sin (t \omega )+2 \sin (t \omega )-2 t \omega  \cos (t \omega )-2 \sin (t \omega ) \cos ^2(t \omega )+\sin (2 t \omega ) \cos (t \omega )}{4 m \omega ^2}\right]$

am I missing something?

Comment: You are not missing anything. It is the sqrt which makes M not able to integrate it. Mathematica does not know vibration theory, so it did not know that natural frequency is sqrt(k/m). It is stuck trying to evaluate the integral with sqrt in it. Using `w^2=k/m` bypass this whole issue. Good workaround btw.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the problem is that Mathematica is having hard time doing the integration when finding the particular solution. Using answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159382/using-the-method-of-undetermined-coefficients/159383#159383),  you can see those integrals in the particular solution.

```
odeH = m*y''[t] + k y[t];
rhs = Sin[Sqrt[k/m] t];
{yh, yp} = hAndp[odeH, rhs, y, t];
solution = yh + yp
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see these integrals are not evaluated, and I think this is where Mathematica is stuck.

Rubi can solve these, giving

```
int1=Int[Cos[(Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]] Sin[Sqrt[k/m] t],t];
int1E=(Limit[int1,t->z]-Limit[int1,t->0]);
int1E=int1E/.z->t
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
int2=Int[Sin[Sqrt[k/m] t] Sin[(Sqrt[k] t)/Sqrt[m]],t];
int2E=(Limit[int2,t->z]-Limit[int2,t->0]);
int2E=int2E/.z->t
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you have the full solution after plugging the above

```
C[1]*Cos[(Sqrt[k]*t)/Sqrt[m]] + C[2]*Sin[(Sqrt[k]*t)/Sqrt[m]] + 
  ((-Cos[(Sqrt[k]*t)/Sqrt[m]])*(Sin[(Sqrt[k/m] - Sqrt[k]/Sqrt[m])*t]/(2*(Sqrt[k/m] - Sqrt[k]/Sqrt[m])) - 
      Sin[(Sqrt[k/m] + Sqrt[k]/Sqrt[m])*t]/(2*(Sqrt[k/m] + Sqrt[k]/Sqrt[m]))) + 
    (1/(2*(Sqrt[k/m] - Sqrt[k]/Sqrt[m])) + 1/(2*(Sqrt[k/m] + Sqrt[k]/Sqrt[m])) - Cos[(Sqrt[k/m] - Sqrt[k]/Sqrt[m])*t]/
       (2*(Sqrt[k/m] - Sqrt[k]/Sqrt[m])) - Cos[(Sqrt[k/m] + Sqrt[k]/Sqrt[m])*t]/(2*(Sqrt[k/m] + Sqrt[k]/Sqrt[m])))*
     Sin[(Sqrt[k]*t)/Sqrt[m]])/(Sqrt[k]*Sqrt[m])
```

Now you can find `C[1]` and `C[2]` from initial conditions.

Btw, Here is Maple solution, which matches what I have above

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

To see where `DSolve` was stuck, one can use this trace method (thanks to Michael E2) shown here [how-does-mathematica-solve-a-certain-differential-equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135055/how-does-mathematica-solve-a-certain-differential-equation)

```
ClearAll[y,t,m,k]
ode=m y''[t]+ k y[t]==Sin[Sqrt[k/m] t];
ic={y[0]==0,y'[0]==1};
Block[{DSolve`print=Print},
Trace[DSolve[{ode,ic},y[t],t],_Integrate,
TraceInternal->True]
]
```

This shows it is stuck at this line

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is full output

[image: Mathematica graphics]